# I am not understanding php expression for saving values in a variable, bellow is the line of php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$copyrights = $config->get( 'template.bottom_bar.copyrights' );
```

I understand $copyrights is a variable that has some value but pleases someone explains me the right side of the expression

```
$config->get( 'template.bottom_bar.copyrights' );
```

what does it mean 
does 'template.bottom_bar.copyrights' is referring to a file or anything

Comment: Which framework or CMS this code belongs to?

Comment: Configuration file is probably a .ini file

Comment: this seems like wordpress (bottom-bar.php)

Comment: It belongs from wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Some frameworks allow dot notation to access array elements.

In this case,

```php
$config->get( 'template.bottom_bar.copyrights' );
```

This is probably the equivalent of something like (but not quite):

```php
$config['template']['bottom_bar']['copyrights'];
```

I say not quite because, depending on your framework, you might have a `template.php` or a `template.ini` file in a `config` directory. This file will have an array of options. The framework will load the various config files and provide a config object/helper like you have there.

The get method usually handles unknown indexes in the array and simply returns null.

Comment: I would say accessing objects elements than array elements. Inside template class, bottom_bar class, copyrights element.

The template may also got the data from dependency injection.

Comment: @SravanthPujari - Why would you say that? The config classes I've seen and used that uses the dot notation like that has been using arrays (from some physical config file) behind the scenes. So in my experience, this answer is more than likely correct.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am using slim framework. when I parse the data from json (without associate array option), the json covert will change this to stdClass objects. For the same if we use this way  `$config->get( 'template' )['bottom_bar']['copyrights']` you will get an error like you were referencing an object as an array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Oh, may be for config it was using like. I just want to say not on;y for arrays some times to reference objects also.

Comment: It is from wordpress framework

Comment: It belongs from WordPress, I have seen  there is no config directory in my theme's folder rather it has "template-parts" directory.

Comment: actually want to find where the string of copyrights coming from, at the end I found the by inspect element where the above line of code is written,